# buildMenu is called in AppDelegate but not UIViewController

Tags: ios, ios13, mac-catalyst, uimenu, uimenubuilder

I'm attempting to create a custom menu for each view in my app, however it appears buildMenu is not being called in View Controllers. Here's an example:

In my AppDelegate, this code is used, which works 100% as expected.

```
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {

    print("Updating menu from AppDelegate")

    super.buildMenu(with: builder)

    let command = UIKeyCommand(
        input: "W",
        modifierFlags: [.command],
        action: #selector(self.helloWorld(_:))
    )
    command.title = "Hello"

    builder.insertChild(UIMenu(
        __title: "World",
        image: nil,
        identifier: UIMenu.Identifier(rawValue: "com.hw.hello"),
        options: [],
        children: [command]
    ), atEndOfMenu: .file)
}

@objc private func helloWorld(_ sender: AppDelegate) {

    print("Hello world")
}
```

However I need to change the options available in the menu depending on where the user is in the app, so I tried doing this in a UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:Bool){
  // Tried all of these to see if any work
    UIMenuSystem.main.setNeedsRebuild()
    UIMenuSystem.context.setNeedsRebuild()
    UIMenuSystem.main.setNeedsRevalidate()
    UIMenuSystem.context.setNeedsRevalidate() 
}
```

and again..

```
// This is never called
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {

    print("Updating menu in View Controller")
}
```

but the buildMenu in the UIViewController is never called :(

Any ideas if this is intended behavior or if there are any workarounds?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with rebuilding the menu, but you can use the method `validateCommand:` inside a view controller to update the menu options on the fly (i.e. disable/enable a command or change its title).

Answer (score 17):

For **main** menus, the system only consults `UIApplication` and `UIApplicationDelegate`, since main menus can exist without any window and hence without any `UIViewController` hierarchy. That's why your override on `UIViewController` doesn't get called for main menus.

For **context** menus, the system does consult the full responder chain starting at the view.

If you need to update main menu commands depending on their context:

- You could leave `buildMenu(with:)` in `UIApplicationDelegate`, arrange for delegate to figure out when and what changed and call `UIMenuSystem.main.setNeedsRebuild()` when it does change, or
- You could define a private method `buildMyMenu(with:)` in your `UIViewController` subclasses, and arrange for `buildMenu(with:)` in `UIApplicationDelegate` to call it, or
- You could build a static menu in `buildMenu`, and rely on your overrides of `canPerformAction(_:withSender:)` and `validate(_:)` to enable or disable or even hide particular commands e.g. by updating the `attributes` property in your `validate(_:)` override.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124710 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behavior. Quoting from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicommand/adding_menus_and_shortcuts_to_the_menu_bar_and_user_interface):

> Because menus can exist with no window or view hierarchy, the system ***only*** consults `UIApplication` and `UIApplicationDelegate` to build the app’s menu bar.

The same [docs page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicommand/adding_menus_and_shortcuts_to_the_menu_bar_and_user_interface) explains how you can adjust the menu commands from view controllers, and there is a great sample project too, so make sure to check it.